# Creating custom CellRendererCombo in PyGtk 2.0

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk, gtk2

In our codebase there's a custom ComboBox control we commonly use all over the UI. It has not been used in a TreeView and I would like to have that rendered in a cell instead of the stock ComboBox. Any suggestions or starting points would be greatly appreciated. I am a long time .NET dev but have only spent 4 months in Python/GTK world.

EDIT:
It seems I have not explained very well, I think I am still in the .NET frame of mind. I have very tenuous understanding of how GTK works. If I use a [CellRendererCombo](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkcellrenderercombo.html) with a TreeViewColumn I get a ComboBox in the cells of that column. They are the stock standard ComboBox widgets. We have a custom ComboBox widget in our codebase and I would like to use that in this column instead, instead of the standard ComboBox. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Wait, are you saying you don't have it in a TreeView and you want to move it into a TreeView? Because otherwise a CellRenderer isn't going to help you...

Comment: Can you expand your question a little bit, it's unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: The `start_editing` handler of `GtkCellRendererCombo` hard-codes creation of `GTK_TYPE_COMBO_BOX`. To change this, you will need to inherit from `GtkCellRendererCombo`, and implement a version of `start_editing` that returns your custom widget. See [the current implementation](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk/blob/gtk-2-24/gtk/gtkcellrenderercombo.c#L406) for details.